# Converting tm to time_t on windows in UTC - _mkgmtime returning -1

Tags: c++, windows, parsing, c++-chrono

I am trying to parse UTC [ECMA date format strings](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` on Windows.

My plan:

1. Use `scanf` to load the string into a `struct tm`
2. Use `_mkgmtime` to turn that into a `time_t` (I am using [_mkgmtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkgmtime-mkgmtime32-mkgmtime64?view=msvc-160) for this, because it uses UTC time, unlike something like `mktime`, which uses local time).
3. Use `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t` to convert to a `time_point`

However, step 2 is always returning -1 for me, giving me bogus values for step 3.

The `tm` struct seems valid, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string timeStr = "2020-12-01T06:06:48Z";

  struct tm tm = {0};
  float s;
  if (sscanf_s(timeStr.c_str(), "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%fZ", &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon,
               &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &s) == 6) {
    tm.tm_sec = static_cast<int>(s);

    time_t t = _mkgmtime(&tm);
    cout << "YEAR: " << tm.tm_year << endl;  // 2020
    cout << "MON:  " << tm.tm_mon << endl;   // 12
    cout << "MDAY: " << tm.tm_mday << endl;  // 1
    cout << "HOUR: " << tm.tm_hour << endl;  // 6
    cout << "MIN:  " << tm.tm_min << endl;   // 6
    cout << "SEC:  " << tm.tm_sec << endl;   // 48
    cout << "TIME: " << t << endl;           // -1

    // TODO once this is solved:
    auto tp = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t);
  }
}
```

Compiler is MSVC 2019, C++17, x64. I cannot upgrade to C++20, or else I would use the new chrono tools for this.

Comment: Side note: Howard Hinnant, the guy who drafted most of the chrono stuff, released a lot of what made it into C++20 [into the wild years before C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date). You may get the support you need from these third party libraries in C++17 and be almost all set for when you do upgrade to C++20 in the future.

Comment: Not "the" problem, but `== 6` would work better than `!= EOF`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the resource - this is sort of a one-off method, I don't necessarily want to include an entire third part library to do this. I'll definitely look through that, though.

Comment: The bug: 2020 needs to lose 1900. `tm_year` is number of years since 1900.

Comment: @user4581301 do'oh, been looking at this for too long. Thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `tm` structure the member `tm_year` [is the number of years since 1900](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm). Feeding in 2020 means you're actually providing year 3920.

It looks like `_mkgmtime` hates that year. On my system `_mkgmtime64` doesn't appear to work either. It should fit in a 64 bit `time_t`, but definitely out of range for the 32 bit version. I can't find a clear-cut, documented reason for 3920 to be rejected or a cut-off point after which the function gives up. Make sure you have a 64 bit `time_t`.

But none of that matters in this case since we want the year 2020. Adding

```
tm.tm_year -= 1900;
tm.tm_mon -= 1; // valid range 0 to 11, not 1 to 12
```

before converting will fix things up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it looks in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    string timeStr = "2020-12-01T06:06:48Z";
    istringstream in{timeStr};
    system_clock::time_point tp;
    in >> parse("%FT%TZ", tp);
    cout << tp << '\n';  // 2020-12-01 06:06:48.000000
}
```

Using the [C++20 `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), just add `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;` and it now works with C++11/14/17.